# My family has a hand written scroll from japan, what is the meaning please

Tags: translation

My mom was in Japan and my moms cousin husband wrote this on a scroll before he passed away. We never got the meaning. Any help deciphering this would be appreciated. Thank you.

水陸人馬群如雲
美月住处在一筹

I used a translator app and I got three different translations:

Translate app Chinese to English:

People on land and water are like clouds

Miyuki(happiness?) residence is at the top

Translate app Japanese to English:

Land, water and horse group Nyoun
Mizuki residence

Google translate Chinese simplified to English translate:

Water and land, people and horses, are like clouds
Mizuki lives in first place

Google translate Japanese to English

Land and Sea People and Horses Nyoun
Mizuki lives in one house

I’m trying to figure out the meaning. Any help I would be grateful! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

水陆人马群如云美月住处在一筹

In this text: 孔明（诸葛亮）祁山布八阵 I found 水陆 and 人马。

(Probably too much war！)
水陆困乏,人马猖狂。
Water and land are exhausted, people and horses are rampant

技高一筹：more skillful
更胜一筹: superior, better
略胜一筹：slightly better, a cut above
略逊一筹: not as good

I have no idea about Japanese, and my Chinese is also not good, so this is just a guess.

水陆人马群如云
（By） water and land, groups of people and horses like clouds,
美月住处在一筹
(The) Beautiful moon residence is better

Tako Queen? Queen of tacos??